Should I Stick to an Older Version of Qiskit Due to Tutorial Compatibility Issues?
I'm new to quantum computing and have recently started exploring Qiskit. I noticed that a new version was released in February, and since then, I've encountered some issues where many of the examples and tutorials no longer work as expected. This has made my progress a bit slower than anticipated.
Given these challenges, I'm considering the option of working with an older version of Qiskit that might be more stable and compatible with existing learning resources.
In addition to this, I’m curious about whether you use Qiskit or other quantum computing providers. Which ones would you personally recommend and why?
I'm curious to hear your thoughts on this. Do you think it makes sense to use an older version for learning purposes? Or should I try to adapt to the latest version despite the hiccups?
Any advice or experiences you could share would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

In a month, Qiskit is going to start the quantum computing challenge in Qiskit1.0, you'll learn a lot there. Also most of the tutorials are updated to qiskit1.0, and the upcoming releases will be build on these, so its better to learn qiskit1.0

:) Thanks alot for that info!

You should learn the newer qiskit>=1.0.0 version because this newer version is released with emphasis on:

High-performance code base: qiskit 1.x is much better at dealing with quantum circuits with 100+ qubits compared to older versions.
More stable API: There will be less frequent breaking changes and you will be able to upgrade to versions greater than qiskit 1.0.0 by using pip install -U qiskit.
V2 primitives: qiskit 1.0.0 introduces EstimatorV2 and SamplerV2 which are better than their older counterparts. You can read about that here.
It will be easier for users to build upon qiskit 1.0.0, you can look at the examples of separate projects in qiskit-ecosystem.

Another problem with using older qiskit versions is that you will have to manually go looking for the compatible packages for qiskit-ibm-runtime and other dependencies.
Coming to your concern about the compatibility with the learning resources, the online documentation is almost up-to-date with qiskit 1.0.0. And even so if you find some problems you should report them on github. Also, you can post your questions on stack exchange and the community can help you.
I started learning qiskit 0.45 and now I have moved to qiskit 1.0.2, and in my experience I found the migration guide to be very useful.

ok I see its a process and there are good reasons to migrate :) I will stick to the newer version then, thanks alot!

If you are happy with the answer then you should accept this answer so other future visitors know that this response helped you.

This answer might be a little bit too late, but I want to add that for some of other researchers, we are going to stick with older version of Qiskit unless it is absolutely necessary to move to the newer version.
Usually it because there is legacy workflow build with older qiskit. And as long as it still works, no one bothers to upgrade the qiskit version. I know some hardware research labs are still sticking with the ancient qiskit-Terra 0.18 version just because no one wants to risk breaking the already very complicated working flow and the guy who wrote the code who might be the only one understands all the tricks/pitfalls in the code has graduated for years.
